# How to log screen power off/lock

Tags: windows-8.1, logging, cpu-usage

I want to log screen power off/lock events. A substitute would be to log mouse/keyboard idling (from which display powering off can be inferred.

I ask because I frequently find the fan going full blast with the monitor idling. I want to see if there is a statistically significant correlation between the two. I am inclined to guess that if there is a correlation, the cause lies in indexing being active when all most processes are "idle". But this is just one plausible explanation out of hundreds. For reference, I have a thinkpad T440s (a pretty weird machine in my experience).

Couldn't find anything in Performance monitor that fits the bill.

Comment: Have you checked the Power configuration?

Comment: You mean the timers for "no activity"? Yes.  (Added: "Windows"Tag)